# ¿Cómo comparar dos input de tipo "time" con JavaScript o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Deseo restar la hora de inicio y la hora fin para obtener las horas trabajadas.

Quiero hacer esto dinámicamente al momento que cambie de valor un input pero no encuentro como hacerlo mediante input tipos time, hay desde input tipo text pero no me funciona con time.

¿Cuál sería el formato correcto?

```js
function Horas(i) {

  var jornada1 = 0;
  var jornada2 = 0;
  var permiso = 0;
  var Horatotal = 0;
  var Entrada = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiHoring" + i).value);
  var Salidaalm = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiSalalm" + i).value);
  var Entrada = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiEntalm" + i).value);
  var Salida = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiHorsal" + i).value);
  var horasmañana = 0;
  var horastarde = 0;
  var horasfinales = 0;
  alert(Entrada);
  Horatotal = Salidaalm.diff(Entrada, 'hours', true);

  alert(Horatotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered " width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-success">
      <th>Nombres y Apellidos</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Ingreso</th>
      <th>Salida almuerzo</th>
      <th>Ingreso almuerzo</th>
      <th>Salida</th>
      <th>Salida permiso</th>
      <th>Ingreso permiso</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Total horas</th>
      <th>Total horas cincuenta</th>
      <th>Total horas cien</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="codigo0" name="codigo[]" value="CONT00001" class="form-control codigo" size="30" readonly="true">
      <input type="hidden" id="cedula0" name="cedula[]" value="2147483647" class="form-control cedula" size="30" readonly="true">
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre0" name="nombre[]" value="JOSE LUIS LOOR ANDRADE" class="form-control nombre" size="30" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldSeasiDescri0" name="fieldSeasiDescri[]" class="form-control sueldo"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHoring0" name="fieldSeasiHoring[]" value="06:00" class="form-control bono" placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(0)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalalm0" name="fieldSeasiSalalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(0)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntalm0" name="fieldSeasiEntalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(0)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHorsal0" name="fieldSeasiHorsal[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(0)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntper0" name="fieldSeasiEntper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalper0" name="fieldSeasiSalper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTipoxx0" name="fieldSeasiTipoxx[]" value="30.50" class="form-control dtmensual"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTothor0" name="fieldSeasiTothor[]" value="0" class="form-control cdmensual" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohoca0" name="fieldSeasiTohoca[]" class="form-control freserva" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohocn0" name="fieldSeasiTohocn[]" class="form-control hextrascin" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="codigo1" name="codigo[]" value="CONT00002" class="form-control codigo" size="30" readonly="true">
      <input type="hidden" id="cedula1" name="cedula[]" value="230005953" class="form-control cedula" size="30" readonly="true">
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre1" name="nombre[]" value="MARCELA ESTEFANIA BONILLA BARRAGAN" class="form-control nombre" size="30" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldSeasiDescri1" name="fieldSeasiDescri[]" class="form-control sueldo"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHoring1" name="fieldSeasiHoring[]" value="06:00" class="form-control bono" placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(1)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalalm1" name="fieldSeasiSalalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(1)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntalm1" name="fieldSeasiEntalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(1)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHorsal1" name="fieldSeasiHorsal[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(1)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntper1" name="fieldSeasiEntper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalper1" name="fieldSeasiSalper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTipoxx1" name="fieldSeasiTipoxx[]" value="30.50" class="form-control dtmensual"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTothor1" name="fieldSeasiTothor[]" value="0" class="form-control cdmensual" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohoca1" name="fieldSeasiTohoca[]" class="form-control freserva" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohocn1" name="fieldSeasiTohocn[]" class="form-control hextrascin" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="codigo2" name="codigo[]" value="CONT00003" class="form-control codigo" size="30" readonly="true">
      <input type="hidden" id="cedula2" name="cedula[]" value="0" class="form-control cedula" size="30" readonly="true">
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre2" name="nombre[]" value="" class="form-control nombre" size="30" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldSeasiDescri2" name="fieldSeasiDescri[]" class="form-control sueldo"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHoring2" name="fieldSeasiHoring[]" value="06:00" class="form-control bono" placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(2)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalalm2" name="fieldSeasiSalalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(2)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntalm2" name="fieldSeasiEntalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(2)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHorsal2" name="fieldSeasiHorsal[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(2)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntper2" name="fieldSeasiEntper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalper2" name="fieldSeasiSalper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTipoxx2" name="fieldSeasiTipoxx[]" value="30.50" class="form-control dtmensual"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTothor2" name="fieldSeasiTothor[]" value="0" class="form-control cdmensual" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohoca2" name="fieldSeasiTohoca[]" class="form-control freserva" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohocn2" name="fieldSeasiTohocn[]" class="form-control hextrascin" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="codigo3" name="codigo[]" value="CONT00004" class="form-control codigo" size="30" readonly="true">
      <input type="hidden" id="cedula3" name="cedula[]" value="1725369548" class="form-control cedula" size="30" readonly="true">
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre3" name="nombre[]" value="PALADINES MERINO ANDREA CAROLINA" class="form-control nombre" size="30" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldSeasiDescri3" name="fieldSeasiDescri[]" value="AUXILIAR CONTABLE" class="form-control sueldo"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHoring3" name="fieldSeasiHoring[]" value="06:00" class="form-control bono" placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(3)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalalm3" name="fieldSeasiSalalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(3)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntalm3" name="fieldSeasiEntalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(3)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHorsal3" name="fieldSeasiHorsal[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(3)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntper3" name="fieldSeasiEntper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalper3" name="fieldSeasiSalper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTipoxx3" name="fieldSeasiTipoxx[]" value="30.50" class="form-control dtmensual"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTothor3" name="fieldSeasiTothor[]" value="0" class="form-control cdmensual" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohoca3" name="fieldSeasiTohoca[]" class="form-control freserva" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohocn3" name="fieldSeasiTohocn[]" class="form-control hextrascin" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="codigo4" name="codigo[]" value="CONT00005" class="form-control codigo" size="30" readonly="true">
      <input type="hidden" id="cedula4" name="cedula[]" value="2147483647" class="form-control cedula" size="30" readonly="true">
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre4" name="nombre[]" value="MESIAS ROSADO CARLA SOFIA" class="form-control nombre" size="30" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldSeasiDescri4" name="fieldSeasiDescri[]" value="AUXILIAR CONTABLE" class="form-control sueldo"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHoring4" name="fieldSeasiHoring[]" value="06:00" class="form-control bono" placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(4)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalalm4" name="fieldSeasiSalalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(4)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntalm4" name="fieldSeasiEntalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(4)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHorsal4" name="fieldSeasiHorsal[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(4)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntper4" name="fieldSeasiEntper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalper4" name="fieldSeasiSalper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTipoxx4" name="fieldSeasiTipoxx[]" value="30.50" class="form-control dtmensual"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTothor4" name="fieldSeasiTothor[]" value="0" class="form-control cdmensual" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohoca4" name="fieldSeasiTohoca[]" class="form-control freserva" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohocn4" name="fieldSeasiTohocn[]" class="form-control hextrascin" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="codigo5" name="codigo[]" value="CONT00006" class="form-control codigo" size="30" readonly="true">
      <input type="hidden" id="cedula5" name="cedula[]" value="2147483647" class="form-control cedula" size="30" readonly="true">
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre5" name="nombre[]" value="ROMAN ESTRADA JAVIER ALEXANDER" class="form-control nombre" size="30" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldSeasiDescri5" name="fieldSeasiDescri[]" value="JEFE DE CAMPO" class="form-control sueldo"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHoring5" name="fieldSeasiHoring[]" value="06:00" class="form-control bono" placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(5)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalalm5" name="fieldSeasiSalalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(5)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntalm5" name="fieldSeasiEntalm[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(5)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiHorsal5" name="fieldSeasiHorsal[]" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(5)"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiEntper5" name="fieldSeasiEntper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="fieldSeasiSalper5" name="fieldSeasiSalper[]" value="00:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTipoxx5" name="fieldSeasiTipoxx[]" value="25.00" class="form-control dtmensual"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTothor5" name="fieldSeasiTothor[]" value="0" class="form-control cdmensual" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohoca5" name="fieldSeasiTohoca[]" class="form-control freserva" readonly="true"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="fieldSeasiTohocn5" name="fieldSeasiTohocn[]" class="form-control hextrascin" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Agrega el código que tengas hecho así podemos ver donde puede estar el error.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) permite hacer operaciones como las que quieres con una un api sencillo:

```
moment().diff([2016, 10, 14], 'hours') // dame la diferencia en horas entre el momento actual y el 14/11/2016
```

Comment: Si me parece una herramienta excelente para los largos procesos que  hacia en js   pero tengo el sieguiente error:
"Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Comment: Arguments: [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 06:00, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object] deprecate/<@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:315:94
configFromString@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:2077:9
configFromInput@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:2441:9
prepareConfig@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:2424:9
createFromConfig@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:2391:40
createLocalOrUTC@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:2478:12
createLocal@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:2482:12

Comment: hooks@http://localhost/siashp/js/moment.js:16:12
Horas@http://localhost/siashp/seasi_asiste/new:285:23
onblur@http://localhost/siashp/seasi_asiste/new:1:1

Comment: el input esta asi <input id="fieldSeasiSalalm0" name="fieldSeasiSalalm" value="06:00" class="form-control " placeholder="hrs:mins" min="00:00" max="23:59" onblur="Horas(0)" type="time">

Comment: function horas(i){ var Horatotal = 0;
        var Entrada = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiHoring" + i).value);
        var Salidaalm = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiSalalm" + i).value);
        var Entrada = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiEntalm" + i).value);
        var Salida = moment(document.getElementById("fieldSeasiHorsal" + i).value);
        var horasmañana = 0;
        var horastarde = 0;
        var horasfinales = 0;
        alert(Entrada);
        Horatotal = Salidaalm.diff(Entrada, 'hours', true);
        alert(Horatotal); }

Comment: podrías colocar parte de tu código aquí: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) o alguna herramienta similar, para poder ayudarte por favor.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jeiel/yr0w9h9x/ listo